# Как стилизовать аудио плеер без JS

Tags: html, css, css3, веб-программирование

Пробовал так:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  background-color: #151313;
  color: #151313;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Ничего не получается. В JS я не разбираюсь, поэтому пытаюсь решить в CSS.
Подскажите простой вариант, как изменить плеер для Chrome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126871/8728290

Comment: Я говорил, **без** JS

Comment: я и кинул ответ где ЕСЛИ пролистать увидеш доступные селекторы

Comment: :) может мне извинится за помощь ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для аудио и видео:

```
    audio {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls,
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    direction: ltr;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure, video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 35px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel, video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    /* We use flex-start here to ensure that the play button is visible even
     * if we are too small to show all controls.
     */
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    bottom: auto;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* The duration is also specified in MediaControlElements.cpp and LayoutTests/media/media-controls.js */
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
video:-webkit-full-page-media {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
audio:-webkit-full-page-media, video:-webkit-full-page-media {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
audio:-webkit-full-page-media::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
video:-webkit-full-page-media::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    bottom: 0px;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
    -webkit-appearance: media-mute-button;
    display: flex;
    flex: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 35px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: initial;
    color: inherit;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-enclosure {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-enclosure {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    text-indent: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button {
    -webkit-appearance: media-overlay-play-button;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    -webkit-appearance: media-play-button;
    display: flex;
    flex: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: initial;
    color: inherit;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container, video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container {
    -webkit-appearance: media-controls-background;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 1 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    height: 16px;
    min-width: 0;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display, video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display, video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
    -webkit-appearance: media-current-time-display;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    flex: none;
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    cursor: default;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 9px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline, video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    -webkit-appearance: media-slider;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 8px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 25px;
    border: initial;
    color: inherit;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider, video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
    -webkit-appearance: media-volume-slider;
    display: flex;
    /* The 1.9 value was empirically chosen to match old-flexbox behaviour
     * and be aesthetically pleasing.
     */
    flex: 1 1.9 auto;
    height: 8px;
    max-width: 70px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 15px;
    border: initial;
    color: inherit;
}
/* FIXME these shouldn't use special pseudoShadowIds, but nicer rules.
   https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112508
   https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62218
*/
input[type="range" i]::-webkit-media-slider-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row; /* This property is updated by C++ code. */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.35);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: transparent; /* Background drawing is managed by C++ code to draw ranges. */
}
/* The negative right margin causes the track to overflow its container. */
input[type="range" i]::-webkit-media-slider-container > div {
    margin-right: -14px;
}
input[type="range" i]::-webkit-media-slider-thumb {
    margin-left: -7px;
    margin-right: -7px;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    -webkit-appearance: media-enter-fullscreen-button;
    display: flex;
    flex: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: initial;
    color: inherit;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button {
    -webkit-appearance: media-toggle-closed-captions-button;
    display: flex;
    flex: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: initial;
    color: inherit;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-slider, video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-slider {
    display: none;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-min-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-min-button {
    display: none;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-max-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-max-button {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font: 22px sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    word-break: break-word;
    flex: 1 1;
}
video::cue {
    display: inline;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 2px 2px;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-region {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 5.33vh;
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-region-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-region-container.scrolling {
    transition: top 433ms linear;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-display {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
video::cue(:future) {
    color: gray;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-container b {
    font-weight: bold;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-container u {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-container i {
    font-style: italic;
}
```